# How to check if an order is shipped by API?

Tags: shipping, api, soap

I'm working on a task that need to check if an order is shipped by magento backend or by API. My question is how I can know that an order is shipped by API

Because I noticed that when shipped by API the bundle product, somehow the qty is wrong

File app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Service\Order.php

```
public function prepareShipment($qtys = array())
    {
        $this->updateLocaleNumbers($qtys);
        $totalQty = 0;
        $shipment = $this->_convertor->toShipment($this->_order);
        foreach ($this->_order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            if (!$this->_canShipItem($orderItem, $qtys)) {
                continue;
            }

            $item = $this->_convertor->itemToShipmentItem($orderItem);

            if ($orderItem->isDummy(true)) {
                $qty = 0;
                if (isset($qtys[$orderItem->getParentItemId()])) {
                    $productOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                    if (isset($productOptions['bundle_selection_attributes'])) {
                        $bundleSelectionAttributes = unserialize($productOptions['bundle_selection_attributes']);

                        if ($bundleSelectionAttributes) {
                            $qty = $bundleSelectionAttributes['qty'] * $qtys[$orderItem->getParentItemId()];
                            $qty = min($qty, $orderItem->getSimpleQtyToShip());

                            $item->setQty($qty);
                            $shipment->addItem($item);
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            $qty = 1;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $qty = 1;
                }
            } else {
                if (isset($qtys[$orderItem->getId()])) {
                    $qty = min($qtys[$orderItem->getId()], $orderItem->getQtyToShip());
                } elseif (!count($qtys)) {
                    $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            $totalQty += $qty;
            $item->setQty($qty);
            $shipment->addItem($item);
        }

        $shipment->setTotalQty($totalQty);
        return $shipment;
    }
```

File app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Api\V2.php

```
public function create($orderIncrementId, $itemsQty = array(), $comment = null, $email = false,
        $includeComment = false
    ) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
        $itemsQty = $this->_prepareItemQtyData($itemsQty);
        /**
          * Check order existing
          */
        if (!$order->getId()) {
             $this->_fault('order_not_exists');
        }

        /**
         * Check shipment create availability
         */
        if (!$order->canShip()) {
             $this->_fault('data_invalid', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cannot do shipment for order.'));
        }

         /* @var $shipment Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment */
        $shipment = $order->prepareShipment($itemsQty);
        if ($shipment) {
            $shipment->register();
            $shipment->addComment($comment, $email && $includeComment);
            if ($email) {
                $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
            }
            $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            try {
                $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($shipment)
                    ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                    ->save();
                $shipment->sendEmail($email, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
            }
            return $shipment->getIncrementId();
        }
        return null;
    }
```